# compile handlebars template with Brunch.io

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, brunch

I'm using brunch.io together with [Handlebars plugin](https://github.com/brunch/handlebars-brunch).
In order to compile my template, i need to get the template and for what i understood i should be able to do it with require()

So something like this should work:

```
var tmp = require('./templates/projects');
var template = Handlebars.compile(tmp);
var compiledHtml = template(data); //data is a var with data for the template inside
viewEl.innerHTML = template; //viewEl is id of div where i want to show the tmpl
```

But if i do so, i don't get error while building, instead i get it when i check in the browser:

```
initialize.js:52 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'templates/projects' from 'initialize.js'
```

where initialize.js is the my main source js file.

for my understanding, it doesn't work because my template isn't compiled in my public folder under public/javascript/app.js as per my config file:

```
module.exports = {
  // See http://brunch.io for documentation.
  files: {
    javascripts: {
        joinTo: {
            'js/app.js': /^app/
        }
    },
    stylesheets: {joinTo: 'css/main.css'},
    templates: { joinTo: 'js/app.js'}
  }
}
```

Or am I really missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

Looks like that handlebars-brunch plugin and static-handlebars-brunch plugin don't work together.

Once i uninstall static-handlebars-brunch, i can see my handlebars template compiled into my app.js